# UITableView scroll like Facebook's slide-in menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Perhaps you have seen the Facebook's iPhone app, and its slide-in menu.

When you scroll it up you can see that the headers of each group stop on top, until the next header takes its place. And vice-versa: by scrolling down, when the content of a group has appeared entirely, the header sticks to the group and starts scrolling with it, leaving the place for the upcoming header.

If anyone knows how is it done, please help. I don't know how this effect is called, I was googling but no result.

Any help (tut, link, code) is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're talking about the sidebar on the left-hand-side, with "Favorites", "Groups", "Apps", etc., correct?

Comment: yop! this one. I need to implement this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This effect (if I understand you correctly) is built into the `UITableView` functionality- the method you're looking for is:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

(Documentation for this method can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3atitleForHeaderInSection%3a)).

By giving your `UITableView` a section header, you will enable the type of *effect* you see in apps like Phone (in the Contacts section).

---

To get headers that *look* like Facebook's as well, you can use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

(Documentation for this method can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a)).

This function allows you to pass a custom view to the UITableView to use as a section header.

Comment: Precisely- in fact, adding something along the lines of `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %i",section }` to your code should allow you to see the effect immediately.